# How to change fontsize of \namesection in latex?

Tags: text, latex, overleaf

In code bellow:

```
\namesection{}{John Doe}{ 
\urlstyle{same}
\href{mailto:john.doe@gmail.com}{john.doe\char`@gmail.com} | 666 666 666\\
\href{https://github.com/johndoe}{github.com/johndoe}
}
```

[image]

I would like to make "John Doe" smaller. Unfortunately I only found the way to make all fonts in \namesection smaller, not the "John Doe" string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found it!

```
% Name command
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{20pt}{30pt}
```

line 42 in .cls file.